# Project raised exception class EListError with message 'List index out of bound (1)'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I made simple clicker game and i want to show my speed of clicking, in graph.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, TeEngine, Series, TeeProcs, Chart;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Chart1: TChart;
    Series1: TLineSeries;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;
  clicks_total,i: integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
Timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
clicks_total:=clicks_total+1;
Label2.Caption:=IntToStr(clicks_total);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
clicks_total:=0;
i:=1;
end;

procedure TForm2.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var clicks_total_support:integer;
begin
i:=i+1;
clicks_total_support:=clicks_total;
Chart1.Series[1].AddXY(i,clicks_total_support,'Hello',clBlue);
clicks_total_support:=1;
end;

end.
```

I want to make every second a point in graph where X will be only 1 greater and Y (height of point) will be that clicks user made in one second. But after 1 second running the code, it will crash with error that's in name of this question. Someone help?

Comment: Use 0-based index to access chart series, or use `Series1.AddXY` directly.

Comment: Also note that you can't rely on `TTimer`'s accuracy. If this is essential for your game, you need to find some other clock source.